# Как применить функцию к нужному элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция

```
    indentRub: function() {
    $('.ab_form-col').on('input.ab_input--rubl', 'input.ab_input--rubl[type="text"]', function() {
        let lengthInputRub = $(this).val().length; // Подсчет символов в инпуте

        if (lengthInputRub >= 1) {
            $('.js-ruble-before').css('left', '210px');
        } else {
            $('.js-ruble-before').css('left', '10px');
        }

    });
},
```

На странице 2 таких формы, классы тоже одинаковые. Нужно чтобы функция применялась к 1 элементу, т.е. в который вводится значение. Это `input` и около него `div` с классом `js-ruble-before` к которому должно примениться условие. Проблема в том, что условие применяется ко всем элементам с данным классом

Comment: Так применяйте [к нужному](https://api.jquery.com/find/), а не ко всем...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно искать относительно *this*, который в данном случае и будет текущим полем ввода.

В простом случае, когда элемент с классом *js-ruble-before* находится сразу после или сразу перед можно воспользоваться методами [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).prev('.js-ruble-before')
$(this).next('.js-ruble-before')
```

Либо стоит подняться до самой формы с помощью метода [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), и искать внутри нее с помощью метода [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).closest('.ab_form-col').find('.js-ruble-before')
```

Answer (score -1):

У Вас небыло коректного обработчика.
Я использовал "**keyup**" метод отпускания клавиши ([описание](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_keyup))
Как верно было описано в коментариях, нужно исходить от **this**, это будет елемент **input.ab_input--rub**. Оператор if можно переписать в 1 строчку использую другой оператор **(условие) ? true : false**.

Пример кода: https://jsfiddle.net/bearwolf/y1j1sjng/2/

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".ab_form-col input.ab_input--rub", function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.closest('.ab_form-col').find('.js-ruble-before').css({left: _this.val().length>=1 ? '210px' : '10px'});       
    });
```

```css
form{
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position:relative;  
}
.js-ruble-before{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ab_form-col">
  <input type="text" class="ab_input--rub">
  <div class="js-ruble-before">
    Что то...
  </div>
</form>

<form class="ab_form-col">
  <input type="text" class="ab_input--rub">
  <div class="js-ruble-before">
    Что то...
  </div>
</form>
```